How to add custom filter on category Page in Magento246
Magento246 how to add custom filter with options on category listing page.
Like...https://prnt.sc/7ZtTc1kGqVJR

Please tag your questions with the existing [tag:magento2.4.6] tag. Creating a new tag is unnecessary in this case and will cause confusion.
